# In UpSetR, how to show decimal number on the intersection bar

Tags: r, upsetr

I am making an upset diagram for the following data in percentages. This is a dummy example for my more complicated data.

> x <- c(a=80, b=9.9, c=5, 'a&b'=0.1, 'a&c'=1.65, 'c&b'=3.35)
>   upset(fromExpression(x), order.by = "freq")

I want these percentages to appear as decimal numbers and all the bars visible even if it is 0.1%. All the data is important in this plot.

Answer (score 2):

### The upset'ting plot

```r
library(UpSetR)
x <- c(a=80, b=9.9, c=5, 'a&b'=0.1, 'a&c'=1.65, 'c&b'=3.35) 
upset(fromExpression(x), order.by = "freq", show.numbers = 'yes')
```

[image]

### Your question

So you want two things:

- percentages to appear as decimal numbers
- bars visible even if it is 0.1%

#### Percentages to appear as decimal numbers

You start by converting your vector of percentages to counts (integer) with `fromExpression`. So the input to `upset` is then a dataframe:

```r
library(UpSetR)
x <- c(a=80, b=9.9, c=5, 'a&b'=0.1, 'a&c'=1.65, 'c&b'=3.35) 
str(fromExpression(x))
#> 'data.frame':    98 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ a: num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#>  $ b: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ c: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

`upset` internally then gets the labels from this data, so the link to your original percentages is no longer present inside `upset`.

Having labels as percentages, or some other custom labels, does not seem to be a supported option for the function `upset` from the `UpSetR` package at the moment.

There is the `show.numbers` argument but only allow to show those absolute frequencies on top of the bars (`show.numbers = "yes"` or `show.numbers = "Yes"`) or not (any other value for `show.numbers`), here's the code bit involved:

https://github.com/hms-dbmi/UpSetR/blob/fe2812c8cbe87af18c063dcee9941391c836e7b2/R/MainBar.R#L130-L132

So I think you need to change that piece of code, i.e., the `geom_text` and `aes_string`, to use a different aesthetic mapping (your relative frequencies). So maybe ask the developer to do it?

#### Bars visible even if it is 0.1%

Well, this ultimately depends on your y-axis dynamic range and the size of your plot, i.e., if the tallest bar is a lot greater than the shortest than it might be impossible to see both in the same chart (unless you make y-axis discontinuous).

### Conclusion

I understand this is not really a solution to your problem but it is an answer that hopefully points you in the direction of the solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed comment. I now multiplying percentages by 10 and changing the output pdf in Inkscape. This is a one time plot, so it works.

Answer (score 2):

Two facts are standing in the way of a quick and easy solution to this problem:

#### **`UpSetR` is very strongly oriented toward discrete sets of countable objects.**

A potential solution would be instead of using whole objects to use fractional objects, but the first thing `upset()` does is to check for which columns of your data frame have `"0"` and `"1"` as their only levels. This is hardcoded. If this fails, the `startend` object becomes `NULL` and there is no way the function will be able to do anything.

#### `UpSetR` does not give very good access to the plots it creates.

Once the plots are made, you are left with no return value from `upset()`. This means you cannot modify the plot objects themselves or change way they are plotted outside of the arguments allowed to pass to `upset()`.

So, what can you do?

- Depending on how complicated your real plot is (and how often have to replot it) you might just do this:

```
x <- c(a=80, b=9.9, c=5, 'a&b'=0.1, 'a&c'=1.65, 'c&b'=3.35) 
upset(fromExpression(x*100), order.by = "freq")
```

and then edit in inkscape/illustrator. (BAD)

- Fork `UpSetR` and hijack the `scale.intersections` and `scale.sets` parameters. In the `Make_main_bar()` function you would just change the way it handles a "percent" argument to `scale_intersections`, and change the way `Make_size_plot()` handles the same argument to `scale_sets`. This would then become:

```
x <- c(a=80, b=9.9, c=5, 'a&b'=0.1, 'a&c'=1.65, 'c&b'=3.35) 
upset(fromExpression(x*100), order.by = "freq",
      scale.intersections="percent", scale.sets="percent")
```

I have personally forked `UpSetR` myself for other purposes, but the package in general needs a major refactoring so that it might be applied to additional use cases. The authors may have wanted to prevented uses of the concept outside of their concept.